# RadGrid Double Click with Single Click

Tags: javascript, telerik, radgrid, double-click

I have a requirement to fire a client side event on Telerik RadGrid Row Double Click, and an update fetching from server on single click. But Double click event doesn't work. If I remove  "EnablePostBackOnRowClick" option, then it works fine. How can I use both? Here is my code

```
  <ClientSettings AllowGroupExpandCollapse="True" ReorderColumnsOnClient="false" AllowDragToGroup="false"
      AllowColumnsReorder="false" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true" >
      <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" />                  
  </ClientSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to separate the low-level 'click handler' from 'single-click' and 'double-click' logic, and set `window.setTimeout()` initially to fire the 'single-click' logic.

If the low-level click handler is invoked again before the timer has fired, then it is is a double-click; and the timer is cancelled.

See Jayesh's example on this forum:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-detect-single-and-double-click-in-itemcommand-of-radgrid

Comment: Answering in links is discouraged in Stack overflow. Provide the portion of that page that answers the question of OP in your answer so that future readers may be able to read it even if the link is broken.